# Why Java reflect can access to private field/method?

Tags: java, code-access-security

In Java, we can write

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Method method = f.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("say", null); // private void say() 
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(f, null);
```

Why Java reflect API can access such method? Any magic of JVM?

Is it some "java security properties" for this?

I try to write bytecode dicty access to such method/field use asm.jar , but fail. it always throws :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.nutz.Abc.name from class sun.net.wendal.V$1
    at sun.net.wendal.V$1.run(V.java:14)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.wendal.V.main(V.java:11)
```

I try to invoke it around AccessController.doPrivileged, but fail too.

Comment: *Any magic of JVM?* Yep. The reflection API is not possible to implement in "pure" Java code. (You need support from the JVM.)

Answer (score 1):

JVM can inspect any class at run time through a technique known as Run Time Type Information (RTTI).This is accomplished through a special kind of object called the **Class** object, which contains information about the class.

The class **Class** and **java.lang.reflect** library supports the concept of Reflection. So using the object of class **Class**, jvm can instantiate and can also call methods/constructor of the class.

Pls check Class API : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 0):

Having private methods, and fields which can be accessed some ways but not others, is magic. Being able to access everything is the simplest case, and the default at the native level.  When you use `setAccessible(true)` it just turns off the access checks which is why you might use it even if you know you have access because it can speed up the invoke()